# Trying to make it so that my text colors will alternate blinking forever but for not working with infinite loop, is there a better way?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a few words in text flash colors repeatedly 
I set an infinite for loop to contain the code but its not working as the time is 5secs
Can someone tell me whats wrong with my code to get the result I am looking for?
Although I dont think the issue is my html file I added it in anyways
I am pretty sure its related to the animation duration time
Thank you in advance

```
$(function() {
 for (var h = 0; h < 1000; h++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('li.color-0').removeClass('hidden');
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('li.color-1').removeClass('hidden');
    }, 1200);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('li.color-2').removeClass('hidden');
    }, 1400);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('li.color-3').removeClass('hidden');
    }, 1600);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('li.color-4').removeClass('hidden');
    }, 1800);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('li.color-5').removeClass('hidden');
    }, 2000);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('li.color-6').removeClass('hidden');
    }, 2200);

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('li.color-7').removeClass('hidden');
    }, 2600);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('li.color-8').removeClass('hidden');
    }, 2800);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('li.color-9').removeClass('hidden');
    }, 3000);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('li.color-10').removeClass('hidden');
    }, 3200);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('li.color-11').removeClass('hidden');
    }, 3400);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('li.color-12').removeClass('hidden');
    }, 3600);

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('li.color-12').addClass('hidden');
    }, 3800);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('li.color-11').addClass('hidden');
    }, 4000);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('li.color-10').addClass('hidden');
    }, 4200);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('li.color-9').addClass('hidden');
    }, 4400);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('li.color-8').addClass('hidden');
    }, 4600);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('li.color-7').addClass('hidden');
    }, 4800);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('li.color-6').addClass('hidden');
    }, 5000);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('li.color-5').addClass('hidden');
    }, 5200);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('li.color-4').addClass('hidden');
    }, 5400);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('li.color-3').addClass('hidden');
    }, 5600);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('li.color-2').addClass('hidden');
    }, 5800);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('li.color-1').addClass('hidden');
    }, 6000);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('li.color-0').addClass('hidden');
    }, 6200);

  /*  setTimeout(function() {
        $('.fly-in-text').remove();
    }, 6400);
*/

  }

 <div class="wrapper">
     <section class="content">
        <div class="columns">

          <main class="main">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <ul class="fly-in-text">
                    <li class="color-0">C</li>
                    <li class="color-1">J</li>
                    <li class="color-2">s</li>
                <br>
                    <li class="color-3">P</li>
                    <li class="color-4">i</li>
                    <li class="color-5">z</li>
                    <li class="color-6">z</li>
                    <li class="color-7">a</li>
                <br>
                    <li class="color-8">P</li>
                    <li class="color-9">l</li>
                    <li class="color-10">a</li>
                    <li class="color-11">c</li>
                    <li class="color-12">e</li>
                </ul>
            </div>


@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Indie+Flower&family=Pacifico&display=swap');

body{
margin: 0;
} 

.wrapper{
min-height: 100vh;
background: #ccc;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  background: #999;
  color: #000; 
}
.columns{
  display: flex;
  flex:1;
}
.main{
  flex: 1;
  order: 2;
  background: #eee;
}

.sidebar-1 {
  width: 30%;
  background: #000000;
  order: 1;
}

.sidebar-2 {
  width: 30%;
  order: 3;
  background: #000000;  
}

/* Welcome Page Animation */

.fly-in-text {
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2; 


 }

.fly-in-text li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 50px;
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 4em;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 2;
  transform: translate(380px, 300px);
 }

.fly-in-text li:last-child, .fly-in-text li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
 }

.fly-in-text.hidden li {
  opacity: 0;
 }

 /* rainbow color setting */
  @-webkit-keyframes flashycolor {
  0%   {color:#FF4D4D;}
  25%  {color:#FFF94D;}
  50%  {color:#40CFFF;}
  75%  {color:#61FF4D;}
  100% {color:#EF56FC;}
 }

 @keyframes flashycolor {
   0%   {color:#FF4D4D;}
   25%  {color:#FFF94D;}
   50%  {color:#40CFFF;}
   75%  {color:#61FF4D;}
   100% {color:#EF56FC;}
 }

@-webkit-keyframes flashycolor1 {
  0%   {color:#EF56FC;}
  25%  {color:#FF4D4D;}
  50%  {color:#FFF94D;}
  75%  {color:#40CFFF;}
  100% {color:#61FF4D;}
 }

@keyframes flashycolor1 {
  0%   {color:#EF56FC;}
  25%  {color:#FF4D4D;}
  50%  {color:#FFF94D;}
  75%  {color:#40CFFF;}
  100% {color:#61FF4D;}
 }

@-webkit-keyframes flashycolor2 {
  0%   {color:#61FF4D;}
  25%  {color:#EF56FC;}
  50%  {color:#FF4D4D;}
  75%  {color:#FFF94D;}
  100% {color:#40CFFF;}
}

@keyframes flashycolor2 {
  0%   {color:#61FF4D;}
  25%  {color:#EF56FC;}
  50%  {color:#FF4D4D;}
  75%  {color:#FFF94D;}
  100% {color:#40CFFF;}
```

}

```
@-webkit-keyframes flashycolor3 {
  0%   {color:#40CFFF;}
  25%  {color:#61FF4D;}
  50%  {color:#EF56FC;}
  75%  {color:#FF4D4D;}
  100% {color:#FFF94D;}
}

@keyframes flashycolor3 {
  0%   {color:#40CFFF;}
  25%  {color:#61FF4D;}
  50%  {color:#EF56FC;}
  75%  {color:#FF4D4D;}
  100% {color:#FFF94D;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes flashycolor4 {
  0%   {color:#FFF94D;}
  25%  {color:#40CFFF;}
  50%  {color:#61FF4D;}
  75%  {color:#EF56FC;}
  100% {color:#FF4D4D;}
}

@keyframes flashycolor4 {
  0%   {color:#FFF94D;}
  25%  {color:#40CFFF;}
  50%  {color:#61FF4D;}
  75%  {color:#EF56FC;}
  100% {color:#FF4D4D;}
}

.color-0, .color-1, .color-10 {
  -webkit-animation-name: flashycolor;
  animation-name: flashycolor;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 20s;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
  }

.color-2, .color-11 {
  -webkit-animation-name: flashycolor1;
  animation-name: flashycolor1;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 20s;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
 }

 .color-3, .color-12 {
   -webkit-animation-name: flashycolor2;
   animation-name: flashycolor2;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 20s;
   animation-duration: 2s;
   -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
   animation-timing-function: linear;
   -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
   animation-delay: 0.5s;
  }

.color-4 {
  -webkit-animation-name: flashycolor3;
  animation-name: flashycolor3;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 20s;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
  }

 .color-6 {
  -webkit-animation-name: flashycolor4;
  animation-name: flashycolor4;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 20s;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
 }

.color-5 {
  -webkit-animation-name: flashycolor;
  animation-name: flashycolor;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 20s;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
 }

.color-7 {
  -webkit-animation-name: flashycolor1;
  animation-name: flashycolor1;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 20s;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
 }

.color-8 {
  -webkit-animation-name: flashycolor2;
  animation-name: flashycolor2;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 20s;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

  .color-9 {
   -webkit-animation-name: flashycolor3;
   animation-name: flashycolor3;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 20s;
   animation-duration: 2s;
   -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
   animation-timing-function: linear;
   -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
   animation-delay: 0.5s;
   }

  .fly-in-text li {
   font-size: 36px;
   transform: translate(0, 250px);
   margin-right: 10px;
  }
```

Comment: Why not just use CSS for this? Can you explain the look you're going for?

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop isn't infinite. It has 0 iterations because `h = 0` is always smaller than `2`.

Comment: He can always just refactor the for loop to `for (;;) { }`

Comment: I changed it to  for (var h = 0; h < 1000; h++) {  But the loop does not flash the letters more than 6 seconds.  I am looking for it to be forever

Comment: Here's forever loop: for(let h=0; h>-1; h++)

Comment: What I am trying to do is use a forever loop to make the colors stay on the whole time. Currently they are alternating colors for about 5 seconds and then stop.  Using the the loop statement above didnt change it.  Maybe I cannot use the infinite loop to achieve this goal.  Any more suggestions?